# How to modify existing contact page?

Tags: templates, contact

So, I've inherited a joomla 3 site to maintain, and the current contact page seems to be custom set up http://greentec-capital.com/index.php/contact: The page has a google map, provided by the google map plug in and then the page is set to single contact. I've toyed around with creating multiple contacts and changing the setting from single contact to multiple contacts, but changing the setting makes the map disappear. From what I can tell, the layout seems to be determined by html files in the template folder "com_contact."

So,

1. how is the map being added to the page and why does it disappear when I change the contact type?
2. How can I display more than one address, but keep the same layout?

From, what I've seen in the template, it seems to coded into the template files. That I'd like to do is keep the layout, but add a second address beneath the first one.

Comment: You will probably need to provide more information e.g. a link to the website to elicit a good quality answer.

Comment: I agree with Neil, we need a lot more context. With what we have now I can guess that 1.) map data is displayed via javascript, when you change the data it removes it expecting a specific type. 2.) impossible to answer with no code to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is the map being added to the page?

The site indicated uses "Google Maps by Reumer" plugin, which is one of the best choices available at the time of this answer for that purpose.

> why does it disappear when I change the contact type?

The map is achieved by replacing a plain text plugin code in curly brackets {mosmap} with the proper Google Maps code. If the map disappears, it means that the changes you have made, have caused that the HTML output of that particular contact does not contain the plugin code anymore.

> How can I display more than one address?

For what I know, Joomla contacts manager limits to one address for each contact.

The fastest and easiest approach to achieve your goal, is through a third party Joomla extension, which allows a custom layout of the form, arbitrary contact details and custom HTML code to place your Google Maps plugin code.

[This one for example](http://www.fox.ra.it/), has a drag and drop visual designer which simplifies the creation of the contact page, it's really cheap, and it provides so many useful features that you'll end asking yourself how you've gone this long without it.

Comment: Thanks, Demis. I have found that the map is being added directly through the html. I'm considering hard coding the second address into the html.